# Query parameters for root component in Angular IO

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I have a very simple Angular 4+ application that fetches data from API and displays the data. I believe this should be possible by using just the root component:`{path: 'main', component: MainComponent}`
and QueryParams like `?id=1`.

I am able to fetch the query param, but for some reason my router repeats the route+params part of the URL after the already existing route+params part. For example my local address malforms from `localhost:4200/main?id=1` into `localhost:4200/main?id=1/main?id=1`.

The ActivatedRoute does pick the correct query parameter from the URL but I would like to keep the URL as sanitized as possible. How do I prevent this duplication from happening? I have set `<base href='/'>` as per routing requirements in my index.html.

Module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        { path: 'main', component: MainComponent},
      ]),
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [MainComponent],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window.document.location.href},
    DataService,
    WindowService,
    HttpUtil
  ],
  bootstrap: [MainComponent]
})
export class MainModule{}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-component',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      if (!(Object.keys(params).length === 0 && params.constructor === Object)) {
        console.log(params);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by your `APP_BASE_HREF`

```
{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window.document.location.href}
```

You are telling the app to use window.document.location.href `main?id=1` as your basehref. Angular then appends its own routes to the end of the basehref. This is why you are getting the duplication

```
 localhost:4200/main?id=1(< APP_BASE_HREF)/main?id=1(< ROUTE)
```

Here are the docs on the functionality of APP_BASE_HREF (https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy#description)